# What is the use of n option in cut command?

Tags: linux, man, cut, options, coreutils

I'm learning about the `cut` command. In the man page of cut, they show the `-n` option like:

```
-n     (ignored)
```

But I didn't understand the usage of the `n` option or when we would use it. Can anyone explain with an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `man cut` describes -n option as "ignored", simply because it is not implemented, in the `cut` implementation from `coreutils`.

However, the -n option is implemented on some others `cut` implementations, at least in the *BSD \ POSIX.2 implementation(s).

Thus `cut` from coreutils implements a stub option to it, for portability sake, for not breaking compatibility with scripts. However, as it is not implemented, it won't have any effect using it.

From `man cut` in FreeBSD 12.0:

> -n         Do not split multi-byte characters.  Characters will only be output if at least one byte is selected, and, after a prefix of zero
>          or more unselected bytes, the rest of the bytes that form the
>          character are selected.

From the [POSIX standard `cut` page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/cut.html), link pointed out by @Kusalananda:

> -n Do not split characters. When specified with the -b option, each element in list of the form low- high ( -separated
>   numbers) shall be modified as follows:
>
> If the byte selected by low is not the first byte of a character, low shall be decremented to select the first byte of the
>   character originally selected by low. If the byte selected by high is
>   not the last byte of a character, high shall be decremented to select
>   the last byte of the character prior to the character originally
>   selected by high, or zero if there is no prior character. If the
>   resulting range element has high equal to zero or low greater than
>   high, the list element shall be dropped from list for that input line
>   without causing an error.
>
> Each element in list of the form low- shall be treated as above with high set to the number of bytes in the current line, not
>   including the terminating . Each element in list of the form
>   - high shall be treated as above with low set to 1. Each element in list of the form num (a single number) shall be treated as above with
>   low set to num and high set to num.

Comment: An example of how to use would be even more useful. I tried using it with the `-b` flag, but can't really figure out how it is used

Comment: @Inian the post is more about not using it...

Comment: The Question did mention "Can any one explain with example?"...

Comment: @JeffSchaller It did assuming it had some kind of useful in the concerned implementation, which does not have... I might expand it for use in other systems, when I have the time. Work day here.